# must appear in the GROUP BY clause in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am getting this error:

> ERROR:  column "programmer.pname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: select pname, min(age(doj)) from programmer ;

I have a table called `programmer` and columns `dob`, `doj` with date.

Here `doj` is date of joining.

I want to find the least experienced programmer of all the programmers.

That's my try:

```
SELECT pname, min(age(doj)) FROM programmer;
```

and I got the above error.

What is that `programmer.pname` and what is the correct query for the above?

Comment: You should use group by to find the minimum experienced programmer of all the programmers `select pname, min(age(doj)) from programmer 
group by pname  ;` [sql-group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+must+appear+in+the+GROUP+BY+clause

Answer (score 2):

The [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

```
select pname, min(age(doj)) 
from programmer 
group by pname
```

To find the minimum experienced programmer of all the programmers

```
  select pname
        ,min(age(doj)) mindoj 
  from programmer 
  group by pname 
  order by mindoj limit 1
```

or

```
select pname,doj  
from programmer 
order by doj limit 1
```

You may have more than one minimum experienced programmer(*programmers with same minimum experience*) in that case you use this

```
select pname,doj  
from programmer 
where doj=(select min(doj) from programmer)
```

---

> what is that programmer.pname and what is the correct query for the
>   above?

**programmer**.***pname*** = **tablename**.***columnname***

Comment: That worked. But if I have many rows, those too are displayed. My objective is to display one and only the minimum experienced programmer.

Comment: @zeewagon If I understood correctly then try `select pname, min(age(doj)) mindoj
from programmer 
group by pname
order by mindoj limit 1`

Comment: @zeewagon try this one too `select pname 
from programmer 
order by doj limit 1 `